# how to wait for chrome.storage.sync.set to finish storing data before calling that data?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

just wondering how i can wait for chrome.storage.sync.set to finish before i call the data. what's happening is when dataObj is empty (or length 0), the console only prints out the contents of tabArray on the second call, the first call will show an empty array, even though it shouldn't be. this only occurs when the array is empty, and i'm setting it to be empty in my options script.

options.js:

```
  function clear_history() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get("dataObj", function (result) {
      chrome.storage.sync.set({ dataObj: [] });

      console.log("whats left:", result.dataObj + " " + result.dataObj.length);
    });
  }

  document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", clear_history);
```

popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  console.log("welcome to popup.js");
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ greeting: "hey" }, function (response) {
    var x = response.farewell;
    console.log(x);
  });

  document.getElementById("options").addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("redirecting to options");
    chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage();
  });

  document.getElementById("ten-seconds").addEventListener("click", function () {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      // since only one tab should be active and in the current window at once
      // the return variable should only have one entry
      var tabArray = [];
      var activeTab = tabs[0];
      chrome.storage.sync.get("dataObj", async function (result) {
        if (result.dataObj.length === 0) {
          //create fresh array
          console.log("EMPTY");
          tabArray[0] = activeTab.url;
          await chrome.storage.sync.set({ dataObj: tabArray });
        } else {
          tabArray = result.dataObj;
          tabArray.push(activeTab.url);
          await chrome.storage.sync.set({ dataObj: tabArray });
        }

        console.log("array: ", result.dataObj);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to use callback.

Comment: hey! could you expand on that? what do you mean by callback?

Answer (score 0):

You are using callback with **chrome.storage.sync.get**.

Rewrite **options.js** as follows.

```js
function clear_history() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("dataObj", function (result) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ dataObj: [] }, function () {
      console.log("whats left:", result.dataObj + " " + result.dataObj.length);
    });
  });
}

document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", clear_history);
```

Comment: sorry what did you change in that rewrite?

Comment: Look closely at lines 3-4.